# How to hide GET parameter from URL

Tags: php, html

It is possible to hide get value from url (rozgaarexpress.com/profile.php?id=22) using .Htaccess.I want to hide ?id=22. 
    Then URL Looks like rozgaarexpress.com/profile.php

```
My first page demo.php


I am just passing this url

<a href="profile.php?id=22">HTACCESS</a> 

second page profile.php
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
echo $id;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide the ID parameter, even if you use `.htaccess` to achieve that. I mean you can do it but you will be able to use a single ID when accessing profile.php page which I don't think is the case you want.

You can do it by using sessions like:

**demo.php**

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = 22;

echo '<a href="profile.php">My profile</a>';
```

**profile.php**

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

im sure you asked this question to find a way to avoiding show ID to public.

you can use session in this case like this:

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['session_name']=$id; // Set the value of the id you want to pass.
  ?>
```

and in profile.php page you need this:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $id = $_SESSION['session_name'];
 ?>
```

or you can use [JQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to pass your data.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather take the desired profile ID from the Client. This allows the end-user the option to open two different profiles from the same page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setInputAndSubmit(input) {
  var form=document.getElementById("skfrom");
  var inputEl=document.getElementById("LANG");
  inputEl.value = input;
  form.submit();
} </script>

<form id="skfrom" name="myform" action="http://rozgaarexpress.com/profile.php" method="POST">
  <div align="center">
    <a  href="javascript:;" onclick="setInputAndSubmit(34);">First ID</a>
    <br>
    <a  href="javascript:;" onclick="setInputAndSubmit(22);">Another ID</a>
    <br><br>
    <a  href="javascript:;" onclick="setInputAndSubmit(22);">Same ID</a>
    <br><br>
    You can even receive input from users and send it together with the ID.
    <input type="text" size="25" value="Some other field you want visible">
    <input type="hidden" id="LANG" name="Language" value="English">

  </div>
</form>
```